# How to solve "termsOfUse must be a boolean type, but the final value was: "on"." using Ionic, React, Yup and Resolvers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, yup, react-hook-form

I want to create a registration form, where all the fields are required. I'm using React Hook Form and  Yup for form validaton.
All fields are required, including two checkboxes.
When I submit the form, I get this error for checkboxes:

termsOfUse must be a `boolean` type, but the final value was: `"on"`.

I think that this means I am trying to save the string value 'on' into the yup field, which requires a boolean. This is because of the checkbox is passing target.value instead of target.checked: {...register("privacyPolicy")}

I still don't know how to pass 'checked' instead of 'value' and use checkbox inputs in RHF in general.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you :)

The component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  IonPage,
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  IonTitle,
  IonContent,
  IonButton,
  IonInput,
  IonLabel,
  IonItem,
  IonLoading,
  IonToast,
  IonSelectOption,
  IonSelect,
  IonRadio,
  IonCheckbox,
  IonGrid,
  IonRow,
  IonCol,
  IonAlert,
} from "@ionic/react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
import axios from "axios";

// form validation rules
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .email("E-mail is invalid!")
    .min(7, "E-Mail must have 7 characters")
    .required("E-Mail is required"),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .min(8, "Password should have at least 8 characters!")
    .required("Password is required"),
  termsOfUse: yup
    .boolean()
    .oneOf([true], "You should accept terms of use"),
  privacyPolicy: yup
    .boolean()
    .oneOf([true], "You should accept privacy policy"),
});

const CreateAccountPage: React.FC = () => {
 
  const [checkedTermsOfUse, setCheckedTermsOfUse] = useState(false);
  const [checkedPrivacyPolicy, setCheckedPrivacyPolicy] = useState(false);

  const history = useHistory();

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    getValues,
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });

  const doCreateAccount = () => {
    const data = {
      eMail: getValues("email"),
      password: getValues("password"),
    };

    axios
      .post("xx/register", data)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      })
  };

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent className="ion-padding">
           
          <form
            className="ion-padding"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(doCreateAccount)}
          >
          
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="floating">E-Mail *</IonLabel>
              <IonInput type="email" {...register("email")} />
            </IonItem>
            {errors.email && <p>{errors.email.message}</p>}
            
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="floating">
                Password *
              </IonLabel>
              <IonInput type="password" {...register("password")} />
            </IonItem>
            

            <div>
              <IonCheckbox
                checked={checkedTermsOfUse}
                {...register("termsOfUse")}
              ></IonCheckbox>{" "}
              <a
                href="https://wss-rest.api.woehlke.de/type/agreement-version-content/1"
                target="_blank"
              >
                I accept terms of use
              </a>
            </div>
            {errors.termsOfUse && <p>{errors.termsOfUse.message}</p>}

            <div>
              <IonCheckbox
                {...register("privacyPolicy")}
                checked={checkedPrivacyPolicy}
              ></IonCheckbox>{" "}
              <a
                href="https://wss-rest.api.woehlke.de/type/agreement-version-content/3"
                target="_blank"
              >
                I accept privacy policy
              </a>
            </div>
            {errors.privacyPolicy && <p>{errors.privacyPolicy.message}</p>}

            <IonButton type="submit">Submit</IonButton>
            <IonButton onClick={() => history.goBack()} color="danger">
              CANCEL
            </IonButton>
          </form>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default CreateAccountPage;
```

```
"@hookform/resolvers": "^2.4.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.1.1",
"yup": "^0.32.9"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a native checkbox the `register` call would be sufficient:

```js
<input
  type="checkbox"
  {...register("nativeCheckbox")}
/>
```

But as you are using an external, controlled component with `<IonCheckbox />`, you need to use the `Controller` component:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="checkbox"
  render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
    <IonCheckbox
      checked={value}
      onIonChange={({ detail: { checked } }) => onChange(checked)}
    />
  )}
/>
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Ionic Checkbox]

Check this [section](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries) in the documentation for more infos.

Comment: they keep changing how this works, it is honestly getting frustrating and I am about to stop using react-hook-form... Just updating to the next release breaks code??

Comment: @AaronSaunders Didn't this work the same way in v6 using the `Controller` component? The only thing that changed in v7 is the structure of the parameter for `render` as the `value` and `onChange` properties are now nested in the `field` property.

Comment: I believe during one iteration... in version 6 it just worked, you didn't need to use controllers at some point and also this new format of  {...register('name')} breaks old code completely if you upgrade

Comment: For simple ionic components like `<IonInput />` it is still possible to use `register`only. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-ionic-input-checkbox-2g403?file=/src/index.js And yes, it is a bit of a hassle to migrate to v7 with the new format. But the TypeScript support is also much better now, which made some of the breaking changes like `register` necessary.

Answer (score 3):

try this  `<Field type="checkbox" name="policy" :value="false" />`

add before `:value="false"` behind the Field

```
policy : yup.boolean().oneOf([true],"your message"),
```